# How to not overwrite a file(using append mode)

Tags: java, io, overwrite, filewriter

This is my current code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteToFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public void Write(String content) {
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {

            //Specify the file name and path here
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Gbruiker\\Dropbox\\Java\\Rekenen\\src\\sommen.txt");

                     /* This logic will make sure that the file 
                      * gets created if it is not present at the
                      * specified location*/
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.append(content);
            bw.append("\n");
            System.out.println("File written Successfully");

        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (bw != null)
                    bw.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in closing the BufferedWriter" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that it doesn't overwrite the current text in the text file?

Any suggestions?
Am I doing it the right way? 
The program has to add some text to a file but not overwrite to the current content. Because now it is overwriting the current content.

Comment: Don't continue writing the file if it exists...

Comment: I thought you meant you didn't want to write to the file if it existed, but you seem to mean you want to append to the file

Comment: No problem, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `new FileWriter(file, true);` constructor, where `true` is for appending to the file rather than overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

Change `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);` to `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true);`.

the boolean value append mode.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html):

> public FileWriter(String fileName,
>             boolean append)
>              throws IOException  Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data
>   written.  Parameters:fileName - String The system-dependent
>   filename.append - boolean if true, then data will be written to the
>   end of the file rather than the beginning. Throws: IOException - if
>   the named file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file,
>   does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any
>   other reason